# Use the same ViewController and TableView in a TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following problem. I'm using a `TabBarController` with 5 different tabs for each day from Monday to Friday.

Each tab needs to have only a `TableView` that display some information depending the current selected tab (aka day).

I'm using for every tab the same `ViewController`. I'm using the following method

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```

to detect the current tab bar index and load the data to display in the table. In my idea this method also updates the variable `currentDay` which is used to retrieve the correct data to be displayed.

Below the code I use to get such data.

```
let retrieveOrariofromCoreData = CoreDataController.sharedIstanceCData.load(currentDay)
self.arrayTimes = retrieveOrariofromCoreData
if (self.arrayTimes?.isEmpty)! {
    Utils.setPlaceholderForEmptyTable(self, message: "...")
} else {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.tableView.isHidden = false
}
```

The problem is that I place this code in the `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method, which is executed before the `tabBarController` that changes the variable `currentDay`.

Maybe my approach is a bit rudimental. I'd like to find a more simple and elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know when you change your `currentDay` variable. I have just tested it with `UITabBarControllerDelegate`s `tabBar:didSelect:`, which is executed before loading the viewController.

My testing code looks like the following:

```
var index = 0
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    index = (self.tabBar.items?.index(of: item)) ?? 0
}
```

And then in the viewController in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`:

```
print("loaded \((self.tabBarController as? TabViewController)?.index ?? 0)")
```

which always gave me the correct index.

Comment: In your example you suggest to inherit from `UITabBarController` and to override the `tabBar` method to get the index. However, my controller already inherit from `UITableViewController`

Comment: You need two classes, one inherits from `UITableViewController` (your content view) and one that inherits from `UITabBarViewController`, which manages the tabBar and selection changes.